# To retrieve the bit from LSB insertion

Tags: java, embed, extract, decode, lsb

I read about LSB insertion online, but it only introduces about how to insert bits to LSB, but it didn't describe how to extract the bits. This is the article I read about [LSB insertion](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wm2a/applets/LeastBitInsertion/LeastSignificantBit.html).

I understand the method they use below, but how do you extract the bits?

Comment: Once you know which pixels are the ones that contain the hidden information, you just need to read the least significant bit for each color component of those pixels.

Comment: but that least significant for each color i try to read is not the original bits. some bits changed because inserted binary value 10000011. How to retrieve original bits from LSB??

Comment: If by original bits you mean the bits from the original image, you can't get them back once you apply LSB insertion. There's not enough information  in the modified image to know what the original bits were.

Comment: Yes, i mean the bits from the original image or (binary value 10000011, this article try to embed in). there is no way to get the bits back??

Comment: **1. Original Image** = unmodified image, bunch of bytes before processing. **2. LSB Image** = image with inserted hidden information (e.g. `10000011`) somewhere along the bunch of bytes. Now, if you have image **2** you can get back `10000011`, like mentioned in the first comment. What you *can't* do is get the value for those bits in image **1** if you only have image **2**.

Comment: Yes Juan, thats is what i mean. I want to get bits from image2(modified image, not the original one), but i don't understand how to get those bits back.

Comment: an example in that article, if both bits(binary of letter A and LSB of pixels) are the same, it wont change the LSB of that pixel, but if its different, it will change the LSB of pixel. But don't know how to extract bits. using the same way??

Comment: as you mentioned in the first comment, u said ""Once you know which pixels are the ones", you mean that bit=1??

Comment: I think i got it. Thank you to teaching me. Thank you Juan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm for getting the encrypted message:

1. Read image.
2. Iterate over pixels.
3. Decompose pixel into RGB values (one byte for R, one for G, one for B)
4. Take the LSB from red.  If the LSB is in bit zero, you can `AND` the red value with a mask of 1 (bits 000000001). So, `lsbValue = rvalue & 0x01`.  Place the lsbValue (it will only be one or zero) in the highest bit
5. Get the LSB from green.  Place this in the next highest bit.
6. Get the LSB from blue.  Place this in the next bit down.
7. Read the next pixel and decompose into RGB bytes.
8. Stuff the LSB of the color components into bit positions until you've filled a byte.  This is the first byte of your encrypted mesage.
9. Continue iterating over pixels and their RGB values until you've processed all pixels.
10. Inspect the bytes you've decrypted.  The actual message should be obvious.  Anything beyond the encrypted message will just be noise, i.e, the LSB of the actual image pixels.

Comment: Thank you Ireeder, i understand the step of decode, but i don't understand how to exactly get original bits back from LSB of each pixel.

Comment: LSB is only one bit.  You can get the LSB by masking all but the least significant bit, using one as a mask.  I've updated my answer with some details on this.

Comment: Thank you Ireeder. I understand it now. Thank you.